# how to draw multiple arrow lines in extjs grid panel

Tags: extjs, raphael

i am tryting to draw multiple arrow lines between two grid panels, but i am able to draw only one arrow, when i start to draw the second arrow the first arrow is not showing.below is the code which i have tried.

This is where i am creating a arrow

```
Raphael.fn.arrow = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, size) {
    // alert("raphael");
        var angle = Math.atan2(x1-x2,y2-y1);
        angle = (angle / (2 * Math.PI)) * 360;
        var arrowPath = this.path("M" + x2 + " " + y2 + " L" + (x2  - size) + " " + (y2  - size) + " L" + (x2  - size)  + " " + (y2  + size) + " L" + x2 + " " + y2 ).attr("fill","black").rotate((90+angle),x2,y2);
        var linePath = this.path("M" + x1 + " " + y1 + " L" + x2 + " " + y2);
        return [linePath,arrowPath];
    };


drag initialization

 onInitDrag : function(x,y){
                var data = this.dragData;
                this.ddel.innerHTML = this.grid.getDragDropText();
                //alert("this.ddel :"+this.ddel.innerHTML);
                this.proxy.update(this.ddel);
                // fire start drag?
                //i would say yes ;-)
                this.onStartDrag(x,y);
            },
            /*
            * onStartDrag is called when you initiate the drag action
            * it stores the mouse coordinates and create the SVG canvas
            */
            onStartDrag : function(x, y){
                alert(Ext.getCmp('leftGridId'));
                this.arrowStart = {x:x, y:y};
                alert("on Start Drag :"+x+","+y);
                this.raphaelCanvas = new Raphael(0,0,2000,2000); //could be better...
                //apply body.no-cursor (cursor : none) to hide the cursor
                //cursor:pointer is nice too
                //alert("after StartDrag :"+x+","+y);
            },
            /*
            * onDrag is called on mousemove
            * it clears the canvas and draw the arrow again
            */
            onDrag : function(e){
                //alert("on drag");
                //alert("raphael arrow");
                this.raphaelCanvas.clear();
               var arrow = this.raphaelCanvas.arrow(this.arrowStart.x, this.arrowStart.y, e.xy[0], e.xy[1],8);
               // alert("after mapping"); 
            },
            /*
            * onEndDrag is called when you drop whatever you were dragging
            * it removes the SVG canvas from the document
            */
            onEndDrag : function(){
                alert("on end drag");
                //this.raphaelCanvas.remove();
                //delete this.raphaelCanvas;
                this.raphaelCanvas.renderfix();
                if(!onStartDrag){
                    /this.raphaelCanvas.remove();
                //delete this.raphaelCanvas;
                    }
                    else{
                        onStartDrag();
                        }

            }
```

Comment: var arrow = this.raphaelCanvas.arrow(this.arrowStart.x, this.arrowStart.y, e.xy[0], e.xy[1],8);    you are creating only one ... create two like .... var arrow1 = this.raphaelCanvas.arrow(this.arrowStart.x, this.arrowStart.y, e.xy[0], e.xy[1],8);             var arrow2 = this.raphaelCanvas.arrow(this.arrowStart.x, this.arrowStart.y, e.xy[0], e.xy[1],8);

Comment: your first arrow must be getting removed as you are clearing the paper again and again .... and why are you creating the canvas on every drag event .... ???

Answer (score 0):

There can be serious improvements to your code  but try these quick changes if at;east your two arrows start appearing ....

```
 Raphael.fn.arrow = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, size) {
        // alert("raphael");
            var angle = Math.atan2(x1-x2,y2-y1);
            angle = (angle / (2 * Math.PI)) * 360;
            var arrowPath = this.path("M" + x2 + " " + y2 + " L" + (x2  - size) + " " + (y2  - size) + " L" + (x2  - size)  + " " + (y2  + size) + " L" + x2 + " " + y2 ).attr("fill","black").rotate((90+angle),x2,y2);
            var linePath = this.path("M" + x1 + " " + y1 + " L" + x2 + " " + y2);
            return [linePath,arrowPath];
        };

this.raphaelCanvas = new Raphael(0,0,2000,2000);
this.raphaelCanvas.renderfix();
drag initialization

 onInitDrag : function(x,y){
                var data = this.dragData;
                this.ddel.innerHTML = this.grid.getDragDropText();
                //alert("this.ddel :"+this.ddel.innerHTML);
                this.proxy.update(this.ddel);
                // fire start drag?
                //i would say yes ;-)
                this.onStartDrag(x,y);
            },
            /*
            * onStartDrag is called when you initiate the drag action
            * it stores the mouse coordinates and create the SVG canvas
            */
            onStartDrag : function(x, y){
                alert(Ext.getCmp('leftGridId'));
                this.arrowStart = {x:x, y:y};
                alert("on Start Drag :"+x+","+y);
                //this.raphaelCanvas = new Raphael(0,0,2000,2000); //could be better...
                //apply body.no-cursor (cursor : none) to hide the cursor
                //cursor:pointer is nice too
                //alert("after StartDrag :"+x+","+y);
            },
            /*
            * onDrag is called on mousemove
            * it clears the canvas and draw the arrow again
            */
            onDrag : function(e){
                //alert("on drag");
                //alert("raphael arrow");
                //this.raphaelCanvas.clear();
               var arrow = this.raphaelCanvas.arrow(this.arrowStart.x, this.arrowStart.y, e.xy[0], e.xy[1],8);
               // alert("after mapping"); 
            },
            /*
            * onEndDrag is called when you drop whatever you were dragging
            * it removes the SVG canvas from the document
            */
            onEndDrag : function(){
                alert("on end drag");
                //this.raphaelCanvas.remove();
                //delete this.raphaelCanvas;
                //this.raphaelCanvas.renderfix();
                if(!onStartDrag){
                    //this.raphaelCanvas.remove();
                //delete this.raphaelCanvas;
                    }
                    else{
                        onStartDrag();
                        }

            }
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but still i am unable to draw multiple arrow lines, can you give any other suggestions.